# Do rollbacks count toward edit-related badges

Tags: support, edits, badges, rollbacks, edit-and-answer-badges

In [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges), it's made clear that rollbacks do not count as edits; that is, they don't contribute toward the Editor -> Strunk & White -> Copy Editor badges.

> **What edits do not count towards the badges?**
> ...
> **Actions** taken on the post. Since you are not actually editing anything, actions such as closing, deleting, rollbacks, and converting to community wiki do not count.

Is this also the case for other Q&A-edit-related badges?

- Explainer -> Refiner -> Illuminator
- Excavator -> Archeologist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [question about roll-back and edit time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138598/282094) - `"A rollback is an edit. It changes the content of the post."`.  The [FAQ **vaguely** hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038/282094) at this. Also see the section: "What if my edit gets rolled back?", in the link in your question.

Comment: Also an answer, but don't be confused by the discussion and answers here (Yes vs No) as it's about [counting for Community Wiki Status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60923/282094) but it's clear that a rollback is an editing action. Also [confirmed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134356/282094) that retagging (only) isn't counted as an edit.

Comment: @Rob Hmm... Good finds. I think the distinction is in relation to badges. The link in the question is clear that, for the purpose of edit badges, rollbacks are not edits. So at that level, it seems there's a contradiction between rollbacks generally (are edits) and rollbacks in relation to badges (are not edits [where edit badges are concerned]).

Comment: It could certainly be more clear, and like your prior question this could be duped to the FAQ and the FAQ could be edited **after** testing in the Sandbox to ensure that what was tested and found true then remains true today.